# Does the Stone of Good Luck add to my skill rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I'm looking at potentially adding a Stone of Good Luck to my character's possession, but I'm not 100% certain on how it works or if it's worth getting.

The stone's description says:

> While this polished agate is on your person, you gain a +1 bonus to
>   ability checks and saving throws. (DMG p.205)

I am uncertain if this +1 bonus is also applied to all of my skills, or if it is only applied to ability checks.

Comment: Glad it helped. Well... I guess I'm just assuming it helped. If it didn't help, go ahead and edit this question to make clear the difference between the two and we can reopen this one. Otherwise this'll serve as a good guidepost to the answer "skill checks *are* ability checks," which I believe serves both questions well.